# Filtering records from array with multiple conditions and then sort the result by id

Tags: javascript

Below is my array :

```js
var array1 =[
    {
      "id": 77,
      "selected" : false
    },
    {
      "id": 76,
      "selected" : true
    },
    {
     "id": 75,
      "selected" : true
    },
    {
      "id": 74,
      "selected" : false
    },
    {
      "id": 73,
      "selected" : true
    }
  ];
  
  var obj = { "id" : 74, "selected" : true  };
  
  
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

            }
```

So now I want to first fetch only those records whose selected property is true and then sort records by id in descending order and then **select immediate previous record from 74 whose selected property is true**.

**For eg :** 75 is immediate previous record from 74 whose selected property is true. If selected property of 75 would have been false then we should have selected 76 if we go top from 74.

**Expected output :**

```
 {
     "id": 75,
      "selected" : true
   }
```

**Code :**

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

            }
```

Here I am not getting how to filter records by id = 74 and selected with true and then sort record by id descending and select previous record.

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki :Sorry guys it was because of internet issue my question got posted twice.

Comment: The way this is worded it makes it confusing what you are asking. Is the data guaranteed to already sorted in descending order when you get it as it is in the example? Does it need to stay in that order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const array1 = [{
    "id": 77,
    "selected": false
  },
  {
    "id": 76,
    "selected": true
  },
  {
    "id": 75,
    "selected": true
  },
  {
    "id": 74,
    "selected": false
  },
  {
    "id": 73,
    "selected": true
  }
];

const obj = { "id" : 74, "selected" : true  };
let output = {};

let index = array1.map(a=>a.id).indexOf(obj.id); //Find the index of obj

//Iterate array1 from the index to 0
//Check is selected is true
for(let i=index-1;i>=0;i--){
  if(array1[i].selected){
    output = array1[i];
    break;
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you need the record immediately preceding 74 when sorted descending, here I sort ascending and get you the record immediately after.  Same but easier to code.

```js
var array1 =[
    {
      "id": 77,
      "selected" : false
    },
    {
      "id": 76,
      "selected" : true
    },
    {
     "id": 75,
      "selected" : true
    },
    {
      "id": 74,
      "selected" : false
    },
    {
      "id": 73,
      "selected" : true
    }
  ];

var el = array1.sort(function (a,b) {
  if (a.id < b.id) return -1;
  return 1;
}).find(function (a) {
  return a.selected && a.id > 74;
});

console.log(el);
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.Your 2nd,3rd,4th,5th line is confusing for me.Can you please explain this line??

Comment: The MDN documentation on [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) might help you understand it. The sort function is comparing the `id` property of each item in the array to determine which should be first. The find function is looking for an object in the array that has a truthy `selected` property and an `id` higher than `74`. Because `find` searches left to right, he is sorting it in ascending order before running `find`.

Comment: Thanks @UselessCode for linking the relevant MDN pages.  Nothing more to say really, sort then find is all you need for this exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and test the object, if it match the filter and get the minimum `id` which is greater or equal then the wanted.

```js
var array = [{ id: 77, selected: false }, { id: 76, selected: true }, { id: 75, selected: true }, { id: 74, selected: false }, { id: 73, selected: true }],
    filter = { id: 74, selected: true },
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return a.selected === filter.selected && a.id > filter.id && (r && a.id < r.id || !r) ? a : r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.You have given answers to my lots of question and for all arrays
related question,your answer include reduce function.Is there any performance benefit of using reduce function as compared
to array??

Comment: the reason is to have a start value, check against the actual object and return a possibke result for the next iteration, without the need to have another temporary variable, which is possible, but not as compact as reduce works.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script.

```js
$().ready(function () {
var array1 = [
{
"id": 77,
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 76,
"selected": true
},
{
"id": 75,
"selected": true
},
{
"id": 74,
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 73,
"selected": true
}
];

var filterData = $(array1).filter(function (i, n) { return n.selected === true });
filterData = filterData.sort(function (a, b) { return a.id - b.id });
$.each(filterData, function (i, item) {
    console.log(item);
});
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The question was worded in a confusing way, this isn't what they were looking for. They want the first object after the object with and `id` of `74` that has a `selected` property with `true`, not all of the objects that have a `selected` as `true`.

Comment: Please check his word, there is contradict when filter by id then it will return only one object then why sorting by id? "Here i am not getting how to filter records by id = 74 and selected with true and then sort record by id descending and select previous record."